"Parse error at line: 2, column: 124: Incorrect syntax near '350'." error within an implicit table creation
When I create a table in Azure Synapse SQL Server implicitly, I see the following error:

Parse error at line: 2, column:
124:
Incorrect syntax near '350'.

Here is the script raising the error.
CREATE TABLE temp.test_table
WITH (DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN, HEAP)
AS
SELECT  
    setting.[Company],
    setting.[FileName],
    setting.[Year],
    setting.[Month],
    setting.[Day],
    setting.[Hour],
    setting.[ExpectedNumber],
    row_number() over (order by (select null)) RN
FROM config.settings s
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(s.SettingValue)
WITH (
    [Company]      NVARCHAR(350), 
    [FileName]    NVARCHAR(100),
    [Year]        NVARCHAR(100),
    [Month]       NVARCHAR(100),
    [Day]         NVARCHAR(100),
    [Hour]        NVARCHAR(100),
    [ExpectedNumber] INT
) AS setting
WHERE s.SettingKey = 'quality\check\files';

Whereas I create the table explicitly so everything is correct. I mean the table has been created and populated successfully.
Here you are
CREATE TABLE temp.test_table
(
    [Company]      NVARCHAR(150), -- Update the data type here
    [FileName]    NVARCHAR(100),
    [Year]        NVARCHAR(100),
    [Month]       NVARCHAR(100),
    [Day]         NVARCHAR(100),
    [Hour]        NVARCHAR(100),
    [ExpectedNumber] INT,
    RN INT
)
WITH (DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN, HEAP);


INSERT INTO temp.test_table
SELECT  
    setting.[Company],
    setting.[FileName],
    setting.[Year],
    setting.[Month],
    setting.[Day],
    setting.[Hour],
    setting.[ExpectedNumber],
    row_number() over (order by (select null)) RN
FROM config.settings s
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(s.SettingValue)
WITH (
    [Company]      NVARCHAR(150), -- Update the data type here
    [FileName]    NVARCHAR(100),
    [Year]        NVARCHAR(100),
    [Month]       NVARCHAR(100),
    [Day]         NVARCHAR(100),
    [Hour]        NVARCHAR(100),
    [ExpectedNumber] INT
) AS setting
WHERE s.SettingKey = 'quality\check\files';

If someone can explain to me why this happens.

This is about Azure Synapse, @wqw, which does.

Looks like a bug, or an "undocumented limitation".

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft I think the issue is raised within a table creation with data extraction from json-like strings.
I presume it's definitely a bug. Hope that it will be fixed soon.

After a series of questions under the post, I've concluded that the issue is a bug that it's raised within a table creation with data being extracted from json-like strings (harnessing of CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(...) expression).
By the way a table will have been created without any errors when I don't use the mentioned expression. Here is the demonstration of a successful example
CREATE TABLE temp.test_table10 WITH (DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN, HEAP)
AS SELECT  
     *,
     row_number() over (order by (select null)) RN 
FROM config.settings s 
WHERE s.SettingKey = 'quality\check\files';


